# How to validate a property of a ListViewItem when the property is changed, if the ListView is binded to a ReadOnlyObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have the following VM class:

```
public class SubModuleVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       public string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return_name; }
            set {
            _name = value; 
             PropertyChanged?.(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
           }
        }
}


public class ProjectViewVM:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<SubModuleVM> SubModules
   {get;set;}
   public ProjectViewVM()
   {
           SubModules=LoadFromDatabase();  //loads from database
   }
   // snip irrelevant details
}
```

And the XAML class that corresponds to ProjectViewVM:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubModules}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentModule}" SelectionMode="Single">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>


                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>                                                 
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Take note that the Collection is `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`, not sure whether that will cause problem to the binding or not

When the user changes the `Name` from the `ListView` in the UI, I want to validate so that all the `SubModuleVM.Name` inside the `ProjectViewVM` are all unique. In other words I don't allow duplication on `SubModuleVM.Name` inside a `SubModules` collection. If the user renames it to a value already existing, then I want the validation event ( at UI level) to fire and informs user that this is not permissible, and then the name shall revert back to the old one.

I think that the ListView should have such a validation event available for capturing, but so far I can't find any.

How can I implement my requirement?

Comment: Would removing items in the ListView that are already in use fulfill your requirement on the UI side? Also, you may want to consider implementing the non dupe name requirement as part of the `SubModules` CRUD operations.

Comment: @ShaiCohen, *consider implementing the non dupe name requirement as part of the SubModules*-- can you show how it can be done?

Comment: Sure. I can put some psuedo code together. However if you can add your current CRUD code to your question, I can hopefully provide a more relevant answer.

Comment: @ShaiCohen, I am using a simple `ObservableCollection` list, there is no database involved. There is no need to go to the data level to check the name duplication; if possible, I want to check it at the UI level.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever the set on Name property is called during update or edit of name in list view as you mentioned, try calling logic similar to kind of below snippet :

```
private void Validate()
        {
            var query = SubModules.GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                                  .Select(s => new { Key = s.Key, Count = s.Count() });

            if(query.Any(a => a.Count > 1))
            {
                /* raise notification with some error message or use RasiePropertyChanged("InValid") 
                 * where InValid property in VM is bing to your XAML for indicating error*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where should I put this `Validate` method?

Comment: I din't focused much on your VM structure though. Validate  can be in ProjectViewVM class. So exactly, SubModule should have event say NameChanged. ProjectViewVM should be able to register this event with Validate method (say during load or initialization). Whenever name property is changed, you should be able to fire this event.